# What is the difference between those routes?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.7

I define route for update profile logic, when I used first logic It does not work but the use of second logic works fine. So I don't know what is the difference between those.

```
1. Route::post('/profile', 'ProfileController@update');
2. Route::post('/profile', 'ProfileController@update')->name('profile');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between them, the name, 
so If you put in form action something like `{{ route('profile') }}` you mean: go to route that has name profile.

Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-name-prefixes) for more details.

Comment: This is what I want. I used route in my form. Thanks, @Eyad Jaabo

Answer (score 2):

Routes with name eg `Route::post('/profile', 'ProfileController@update')->name('profile');`

can be accessed in blade using `{{route('profile')}}`

whereas the other one can only be accessed using url(). e.g

```
{{url('/profile')}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one is a 'named route'. It allows you to reference your route by a name.

[Laravel 5.7 Docs - Routing - Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 1):

Well the obvious difference is the added "->name('profile')" named route to your second line. You have tagged this post with laravel-5.7 so I have linked the documentation for this version: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes

It appears to me that perhaps you have some logic in the update function of your ProfileController like so:

```
if ($request->route()->named('profile')) {
    //
}
```

Which would change the outcome of the request. Hope this helps, best regards.